# Ruby ActiveRecord::Base queries adding backticks; need to remove

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I am a noob; got handed this project with no knowledge of Ruby/RoR or
access to the original person who created it.

Anyway, my ActiveRecord::Base implementation is inserting backticks into
the query string sent to Oracle giving me an invalid character error. I
am not sure what to do to remove them.

Code:

```
class QCTestCycle < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_primary_key "TC_TESTCYCL_ID"
end

QCTestCycle.establish_connection(@qc_db[@environment_name])
QCTestCycle.set_table_name "#{@application.qc_table_name}.TESTCYCL"

unique_tests = QCTestCycle.select("tc_testcycl_id").where(:tc_cycle_id
=> @application.qc_cycle_id).group("tc_testcycl_id").all
```

Error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00911: invalid
>   character: SELECT tc_testcycl_id FROM `ONLINE_OLS3_DB`.`TESTCYCL` 
>   WHERE `ONLINE_OLS3_DB`.`TESTCYCL`.`tc_cycle_id` = 463 GROUP BY
>   tc_testcycl_id

Any help on removing the backticks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifying an oracle adapter anywhere?  It's hard to tell what exactly is being passed to `#establish_connection`.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew I would forget something in the post. From the yml file:  adapter: oracle_enhanced (also user, password and DB but I should probably keep those private...).

Comment: So, from that comment, it seems you are using Rails...  Why are you using `#establish_connection`?  Are you connecting to a different DB than defined in `database.yml`?

Comment: Yeah the database.yml points to a mySQL instance whereas this method is pulling from an Oracle DB specified in a different yml.

Comment: Your question about #establish_connection led me down a new path and to an answer (of sorts). For some reason the script is using the wrong driver and issuing mySQL SQL commands to the Oracle DB. Thank you for the pointer; now I just need to figure out how to resolve THAT issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian's question about #establish_connection led me to realize the issue here was that my script was issuing mySQL syntax for an Oracle DB. SO the answer is change the driver... now I need to learn how to do that. Many thanks Brian.

Comment: Glad you got it.  That's exactly the direction I was heading (i.e. not using the correct adapter for the type of DB you were connecting to).  Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.

Comment: You can pass the `:adapter => 'oci'` (or whatever) to `#establish_connection`.  Link to the API doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection

Comment: Not a problem, you helped all the same and I am certainly noobing it up here. Thank you for the help!