# where is the invalid character? oracle 11g on simple sql

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, activerecord, oracle11g

I'm using oracle 11G with OJDBC6.jar adapter.  when I try to run this very simple insert statement, it throws an invalid character exception.

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
: insert into user_defaults values (8526547125,'H214Qa99547')
```

My gemfile is as follows:

```
gem 'activerecord', '4.0.4'
gem 'ActiveRecord-JDBC', '0.5'
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '1.3.6'
```

This is on Oracle 11g with OJDBC6.jar

Comment: Are you sure your statement doesn't have a semicolon at the end? It might be useful to see your code, not just the error.

Comment: I agree with alex - most of the times I had it - it was semicolon in the end. make sure the string you're sending is what you think you are sending - many times the issue is there..

Comment: none of these seem to be working.  I tend to only get these errors when doing updates or inserts

Comment: Is it possible that you use wrong driver like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672534/ruby-activerecordbase-queries-adding-backticks-need-to-remove)?

Comment: Can you try your code with other JDBC version like [ojdbc14.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html)?

Comment: Another error could be a BOM from UTF-8 or some other invisible character - try printing all character-codes from the string...

Comment: Can you upload your file somewhere ? I had got those case of errors when I have some weird char that looks like a normal char (caused by copy&paste for example).

Answer (score 1):

Could this be to do with the inferred column order? Try specifying the columns to remove any ambiguity:

```
INSERT INTO user_defaults (user_id, home_office_id)
VALUES (8526547125, 'H214Qa99547')
```

Comment: Hmmmm... just to confirm, these columns are the *only* columns in the table definition? This is a real long shot - but just to rule it out - could there be any triggers that cause updates elsewhere based on this insert?

Comment: yep... 2 column table id to id maping

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the query is able to be executed directly in the developer tool rather than via java.
   If query fails, then check for invalid data types and correct it.
2. If query is executed successfully in developer tool, then probably some issue in coding, then

   1. Check for query terminator string like semi colon in the string passed.
   2. Try using SOP in your java program to print the query just before inserting.

Comment: I tried the query in Toad and it ran fine.. it's def. a problem with ARJDBC

Comment: Are you able to run other queries? For example, try running a basic select query like "SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL" and check if you are able to get the result.

Comment: I do not have admin previleges to describe User defaults table. Can you post the table structure? At times, non-matching data types could also cause this exception.

Comment: Yes I can run other queries.  Structure is "user_id" number and "home_office_id" varchar 20

Comment: What is size of number datatype?

Comment: 15 characters for the number datatype

Comment: Check if this would help <http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00911_invalid_character.htm>    Also, check if the single quotes is escaped properly in the query string.

Comment: Also, it is a better idea to type the query afresh without copying and pasting to avoid invisible junk characters or new line / feed characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've been burned by out-of-range ASCII in the past. It would be best to rule that out, especially if you've tried everything else that you can think of.

Delete and retype the entire line or lines. Resist the temptation to paste the line after you delete it. If there's a non-printable ASCII character in there, it'll get rid of it.

Make sure that you do this for any line of code that interacts with the SQL statement, whether it be building the string in a variable or actually passing the argument to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

add this line `statement_escape_processing: true` in the database configuration file, like this. This should sort the issue

```
development:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  statement_escape_processing: true
```